# Which compression program/algorithm produces the smallest archive file?

Tags: file-management, compression

I have a directory full of `*.avi` files. I'd like to compress this directory into an archive of the smallest possible size. What compression software would produce the smallest archive file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, the most efficient algorithms would be ones designed specifically for audio and video data, since they can discard unneeded data with [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression), resulting in far better results than generic algorithms implemented by Zip or 7zip. Examples are MPEG-4, VP8 and Theora for video, MP3, AAC and Vorbis for the audio tracks.

Most AVI files, however, are *already* compressed using some combination of those or other algorithms. Compressed data doesn't further compress very well, so with 7zip the best you can expect is maybe 1%-3% reduction, no matter what algorithm you choose.

Your only options are to re-apply video compression again – this way you would permanently lose quality – or to buy a bigger hard drive.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you will not have much compression with avi files, however, most of compression programs have a configuration that allows you to set the compression rate when zipping files. Check on [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) when you add files to compress it will show you a lot of configurations, one of them is the compression rate.

Comment: I tried both zip and 7-zip and I got the same exact size. Will try with "ultra settings". Why don't avi files compress well?

Comment: @Absolute0: Because they are already compressed.

Comment: makes sense. :)